# Alternative monospace fonts

Tags: fonts, typewriter

My document uses the `txfonts` package, which provides Times Roman, Helvetica and what appears to be a facsimile of Courier.

However, I dislike the monospace font and find it to be particularly ugly. I am therefore interested in alternatives that ship as part of texlive. Bera mono is nice however I am more in the market for a serif monospace font as opposed to sans serif.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the Latex Font Catalogue: [typewriter fonts](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html), which are not all typewriter fonts, but I think they are all monospaced.

Comment: This may help too: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213835/using-many-typewriter-fonts-in-a-single-document

Answer (score 29):

I like [Inconsolata](http://ctan.org/pkg/inconsolata) like Khaled does. It's monospaced and it supports several encodings including T1, OT1 and LY1.

Just load inconsolata.sty, you could additionally specify a scaling option `[scaled=factor]`.

Here's an example how the font looks like, taken from [my blog](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/fonts/inconsolata/):

[image]

Links:

- [Inconsolata Homepage](http://levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html)
- [Inconsolata on CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/inconsolata)
- [documentation by Karl Berry](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/inconsolata/inconsolata.pdf) including font tables
- [adding straight single and double quotes to Inconsolata](http://nodnod.net/2009/feb/12/adding-straight-single-and-double-quotes-inconsola/)

Comment: I really like `inconsolata` and I use it in all my editors. The problem however, is that the version from google fonts has the italic/slanted but the latex version lacks slanted. Am I wrong?

Comment: `inconsolata` can break some Unicode characters, at least in math mode, for instance if `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D7}{\ensuremath{\times}}` has been used earlier. A workaround is to put `\usepackage{inconsolata}` before the other packages related to font encoding.

Answer (score 5):

I think most of the easily available monospaced *serif*  (as you asked) typefaces have already been mentioned. One worthy typeface that hasn't yet is [Gyre Cursor](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/cursor). Although it doesn't ship with TeX Live, it's very easy to obtain and install.  I find lots of use for it in small blocks of running text, especially `\url`'s.  It's a nicely reworked `courier` drop-in (however, on that front, I'm guessing you might find it "particularly ugly" :)).

I know you asked for typefaces from the TeX Live distro, but as I have a minor love affair going right now with Adobe's `ITC American Typewriter`, I can't resist mentioning this very attractive font set (see sample below), if only to provide a look at a `tt` typeface that is not, to my eyes, "particularly ugly." Only for running text, however; I certainly wouldn't use it for listings.

[image]

Comment: While certainly nice, this is not a monospace font - just check the width of the "m" and the "i" in "economic".

Comment: Yes, yes, it's a `tt` typeface, not a true monospace font. I appended it to my response because a) I find lots of use for it, and b) it might help out/inspire others who might one day be reading through this posting. Perhaps not "technically" on-topic, but nevertheless maybe "aesthetically" useful given the nature of all of us drawn to producing beautiful TeX/LaTeX created print. I sure hope that's OK by all :))

Comment: TeX Gyre Is included in recent tex live distributions.

Answer (score 4):

I personally prefer either Inconsolata or CM typewriter (usually using LM's).

Comment: Could you expand your answer a bit, e.g. with a MWE on how to use these fonts?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [luximono](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/luximono.html) font. (Note that it is part of MiKTeX, but not of TeX Live.)

Comment: In TeX Live `luximono` can easily be installed by `getnonfreefonts luximono` at the command prompt. Use `getnonfreefonts-sys` to install it to $TEXMFLOCAL instead of $TEXMFHOME. Use the option `-a` to install all available fonts (arial-urw, classico, dayroman, eurofont, garamond, lettergothic, luximono, vntex-nonfree, webomints at the moment).

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Any suggestions on how to do that on Windows?

Comment: @Canageek really late answer... but here we go: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22162/74499

Comment: @aronadaal No kidding, I was working on my undergrad thesis then, and I'm well into my Ph.D. now.

Comment: Yeah, I already thought something like that ;) But maybe it's useful for other people that come to this question.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is dead :(

Answer (score 3):

`\usepackage[scaled=0.8]{FiraMono}`

( Put the above line in the preamble of your document, i.e. immediately after `\documentclass`. )

I use the typewriter font for program code. As such, it is important to clearly distinguish between `1` and `l`, the former being the *digit* **one** and the latter being the *lower case letter* **L**.

I strongly advise against `beramono` because when I copy for example `echo $OS_PASSWORD_INPUT` from the compiled PDF into a terminal it shows up as `echo $OS _ PASSWORD _ INPUT`. Not helpful.

Other good alternatives include `\usepackage[scaled=0.8]{GoMono}`, `\usepackage[scaled=0.8]{DejaVuSansMono}`, but I prefer `FiraMono`.

Reference:
https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html

Comment: Hope `Firamono` doesn't have `italic` version, `Dejavusansmono` is one of a good choice...

Answer (score 2):

My favourite one is `ubuntu mono`. You can easily use with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and `fontspec`!