# How to use the Luximono font with TeX Live?

Tags: fonts, installing, texlive

I've switched from MiKTeX 2.9 to TeX Live 2011 (pretest version). I've managed to integrate some third party fonts (included neither in MiKTeX nor in TeX Live) in my TEXMFLOCAL tree following the instructions given [here](http://tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html). At the moment I'm struggling to install the [Luximono](http://ctan.org/pkg/luximono) font which is part of MiKTeX but (due to license issues) not of TeX Live. According to [getnonfreefonts](http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/), it should be possible to install Luximono (and some other non-free fonts) with TeX Live. Running the `getnonfreefonts` script went smoothly and didn't produce any error or warning messages. (I also manually ran `updmap-sys` afterwards.) However, when trying to compile a LaTeX document that uses Luximono, LaTeX complains that `luximono.sty` is not found.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Of course, I could try to manually download `luximono.sty`, install it in my TEXMFLOCAL (or TEXMFHOME) tree and update the file database, but at the moment I'd rather not corrupt my freshly installed and updated font maps. (I had to deal with a lot of corrupted MiKTeX installations during the last week, which was the reason to switch to TeX Live.) So, to the TeX Live experts out there: What exactly am I supposed to do to get the fonts of `getnonfreefons`, and particularly Luximono, working?

Comment: Adding `luximono.sty` in TEXMFLOCAL does nothing to the font maps. I believe it's already installed as part of the `getnonfreefonts` routine; did you run `mktexlsr`?

Comment: @egreg: I did (and just to be sure, did it again right now) -- `luximono.sty` is still missing. And I checked the contents of my harddisk -- no `luximono.sty`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm feeling really stupid at the moment, but here's the answer: The [instruction](http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) to download the installer and then to run

```
texlua install-getnonfreefonts
```

means that the `getnonfreefonts` *script* will be installed. To install the fonts themselves, one must then follow [these](http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/getnonfreefonts.1.html) instructions and run (in the case of Luximono into the TEXMFLOCAL tree)

```
getnonfreefonts-sys luximono
```

and everthing will be fine (except one's self-perception as a LaTeX power user).

Comment: Hi, I'd just like to remark that the command syntax to install fonts has changed and is now `getnonfreefonts --sys luximono`.

Comment: Seems that the instruction link changed? I was able to install luximono.sty on ubuntu20 using this guide: https://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/
`wget https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts`
`texlua install-getnonfreefonts`
`getnonfreefonts --sys luximono`