# LuxiMono on OS X / TeXShop

Tags: fonts, mac

This is perhaps a very stupid question -- I'm trying to get the luximono font activated for listings in a LaTeX document. I'm not very LaTeX savvy concerning the whole TeX installation architecture. I am on OS X 10.6, and I am using TeXShop. I understand that luximono is not part of the normal tex live installation. So what I did is follow [the instruction of this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22157/how-to-use-the-luximono-font-with-tex-live). I have now

```
\usepackage[scaled=0.8]{luximono}
```

in my document, but the font of the listing looks all bad, some serif font. I get an error message in the log:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/ul9/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 175.
```

I have a hunch that when I ran `getnonfreefonts -a`, there is no environment variables `$TEXMFHOME` or `$TEXMFLOCAL` set, so perhaps it installed in the wrong place?

I have folder `/usr/local/texlive/` on my computer, I don't know if this is the right place, or if the standard OS X ghostscript is somewhere else?

**EDIT**

Maybe this helps: I seem to have two folders, `/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf/fonts` and `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts`. The installation was done into the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It does also require use of package
>
> ```
> \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
> ```
>
> – without it you get wired results.

...found in [a comment to this post](http://miknight.blogspot.de/2005/11/how-to-install-luxi-mono-font-in.html). Now it works!

By the way, it seems indeed to pick up the `TEXMFHOME` installation in `~/Library/texmf` while `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` is wrong (`updmap` looks in `/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf` instead).

Comment: The reason it put the fonts in `~/Library/texmf` is because you used `getnonfreefonts` instead of `sudo getnonfreefonts-sys`. The latter installs in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`.