# Missing u19.map on Mac having used getnonfreefonts-sys to install LuxiMono

Tags: fonts, mactex

I'm helping someone who has a Mac

He is on OS X 10.8.5.
He installed MacTeX and added `/usr/texbin` to `PATH`.
He didn't bother installing `pdflatex` because it seems I got that for free with `MacTeX`.
The instructions I provided him for installing LuxiMono did not work for him (the `dvips/luxi/u19.map` file is missing and I am not sure where to obtain it from). Instead, he installed it using `getnonfreefonts-sys` (as explained here [How to use the Luximono font with TeX Live?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22157/how-to-use-the-luximono-font-with-tex-live)).

He gets the following error:

`[exec] !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ul9r8r): Font ul9r8r at 734 not found
     [exec]  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
     [exec] Result: 1`

Does anyone have a suggestion as to where to download `u19.map` for Mac?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: On CTAN: http://mirror.ctan.org/fonts/LuxiMono/ul9.zip The TeX support is in that zip file, the fonts themselves are in the same directory. The zip file locates the map file in `dvips/config/`, but that should be moved to `fonts/map/dvips/luximono/` (in either your home texmf directory or in the `texmf-local` directory).