# Using consolas as the default teletype style font for listings package?

Tags: fonts, typewriter

Is it possible to use consolas as the default teletype font to display code listings using the `listings` package?
The default computer modern teletype font is too wide for my taste.

**Edit:** I am using regular LaTeX.

Comment: In case XeLaTeX is a valid answer: XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Consolas using either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with the `fontspec` package.

**If you want Consolas to be your default monospaced font for everything:**

Add the following code to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Consolas}
```

There are other options you can pass to `\setmonofont`; see the [`fontspec` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf).

**If you only want Consolas for your code listings:**

Add the following code to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\Consolas{Consolas}
\lstset{basicstyle=\Consolas}
```

Again there are additional options you can pass to `\newfontfamily`.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that works for me is to use the Inconsolata font as detailed in the following [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2247/7142).