# Using many typewriter fonts in a single document

Tags: fonts, typewriter

Reading topics about monospaced fonts, I found out that changing `\tt` font for the document requires replacing only one line in the preambule. For example, I only change the commented line

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% PLACE NEW FONT
\begin{document}
Default
\input{test.tex}
\end{document}
```

to `\renewcommand`

- `\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}` for *Computer Modern Typewriter*
- `\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmvtt}` for *Computer Modern Typewriter Proportional*
- `\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lcmtt}` for *Computer Modern Teletype L*
- `\renewcommand*\ttdefault{lmvtt}` for *Latin Modern Typewriter Proportional*
- `\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}` for *Courier*
- `\renewcommand*\ttdefault{txtt}` for *TXTT*

or `\usepackage`

- `\usepackage[ttdefault=true]{AnonymousPro}` for *Anonymous Pro*
- `\usepackage{ascii}` for *Ascii*
- `\usepackage[scaled=0.82]{beramono}` for *Bera Mono*
- `\usepackage{courier}` for *Courier*
- `\usepackage[scaled=1.04]{couriers}` for *Scaled Courier*
- `\usepackage{DejaVuSansMono}` for *DejaVu Sans Mono*
- `\usepackage[defaultmono]{droidmono}` for *Droid Sans Mono*
- `\usepackage{inconsolata}` for *Inconsolata*
- `\usepackage{kpfonts}` for *KP Monospaced*
- `\usepackage{lmodern}` for *Latin Modern*
- `\usepackage[zerostyle=d]{newtxtt}` for *New TXTT*
- `\usepackage[ocr-a]{ocr}` for *OCR-A Optical Character Recognition Font A*
- `\usepackage{ocr}` for *OCR-B Optical Character Recognition Font B*
- `\usepackage{pxfonts}` for *PX Fonts*
- `\usepackage{tgcursor}` for *TeX Gyre Cursor*
- `\usepackage[scaled=1.05,proportional,lightcondensed]{zlmtt}` for *Latin Modern Typewriter Z*
- `\usepackage{luximono}` for *LuxiMono* (needed `getnonfreefonts luximono`)
- `\usepackage[scaled=1.05]{ulgothic}` for *Letter Gothic* (needed `getnonfreefonts lettergothic`)

In the `test.tex` I simply use `{\ttfamily ... }` and I get selected font instead of default `\tt`.

What should I do to use the **all** listed above fonts in **the same document**?

The *idea* is something like this

```
\begin{document}
Default
\input{test.tex}
% Switch to AnonymousPro
\input{test.tex}
% Switch to ...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to run a test document which includes the typewriter font alongside other styles (e.g. to test how well a particular typewriter font works with a serif used for body text) or you just don't like typing, this example provides a couple of commands for convenience:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand*\ttfontstotry{cmtt,cmvtt,lcmtt,lmvtt,pcr,txtt}% add additional families here, separated by commas
\makeatletter
  \newcommand*\myttfontstest{% defines the actual test command
    \@for \xx:=\ttfontstotry \do {% loops through the families
      \par family: \xx\par
      \renewcommand*\ttdefault{\xx}%
      \input{test}%
    }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{test.tex}% just for testing
    ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

    Oh, jinxed quartz of black sphinx, go hear my vow!

    {\ttfamily
      ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

      abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

      Oh, jinxed quartz of black sphinx, go hear my vow!}

\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

  \myttfontstest% try them out!

\end{document}
```

[image: typewriter variants with default serif]

Comment: Fonts `ascii` and `cm pica` work with `\newfont`. Do they have families?

Comment: @user2793410 `ascii` is a font family but it is defined only in the package file, and it uses the 'raw' encoding `U`. The `README` for `cmpica` states that 'A modified version of the original companion LaTeX [2.09] style can be
found floating around on the net if one looks hard.' I'd assume if a family is declared anywhere, it would be there (assuming that 'modified' means 'updated for LaTeX-2e').

Comment: @Down-voter Any particular reason? Or just general animus?

Answer (score 14):

[image: preview]

You can just use the font family without making it the default. For the packages you need to check their documentation the name of the font family used, then use it in the same way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}


{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont abcdef 123}

{\fontfamily{cmvtt}\selectfont abcdef 123}

{\fontfamily{lcmtt}\selectfont abcdef 123}

{\fontfamily{lmvtt}\selectfont abcdef 123}

{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont abcdef 123}

{\fontfamily{txtt}\selectfont abcdef 123}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does _No file `T1something.fd`_ mean that `something` is not the name of the font family?

Comment: @user2793410 it could mean that, or it could mean that is the name, but you do not have the font installed or (least likely) the font package does not use `.fd` files but includes the definitions directly in the package.

Comment: @user2793410 Or it could mean that the font family is not available with the T1 encoding but only set up to support (an)other encoding(s).

Answer (score 8):

David Carlisle's answer is about changing *current* font. The answer from cfr changes `\ttdefault`.
I cannot call my solution complete because I couldn't make it for all the fonts. Looking for font families names took me some time. So I put them in my own answer.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Store the default font
\edef\oldtt{\ttdefault}
% Fonts from packages
\usepackage{ascii}
\usepackage[scale=1.05,ttdefault=true]{AnonymousPro}
\usepackage[scaled=0.84]{beramono}
\usepackage[scaled=1.04]{couriers}
\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{DejaVuSansMono}
\usepackage[defaultmono]{droidmono}
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{inconsolata}
   %\usepackage{kpfonts}
   % ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package textcomp.
   %\ifkp@text\ifkp@textcomp\RequirePackage[full]{textcomp}\fi\fi
\usepackage[nomath,notext]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[scaled=0.84]{luximono} % getnonfreefonts luximono
\usepackage[zerostyle=d,scaled=0.96]{newtxtt}
   %\usepackage{ocr}
\usepackage[scaled=.93]{newtxtext}
   %\usepackage{pxfonts}
   %\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{tgcursor}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{ulgothic} %  getnonfreefonts lettergothic
\usepackage[scaled=1.20,proportional,lightcondensed]{zlmtt}

\addtolength{\voffset}{-1.5cm}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-2.0cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{3.0cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{4.0cm}

\begin{document}
% The last one
\ttdefault\\ % why do I get zlmvtt?
\input{testtt}

% Back to default
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{\oldtt}
Default\\
\input{testtt}

pcr\\
{\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr} \input{testtt}}

cmtt\\
{\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt} \noindent\input{testtt}}

cmvtt\\
{\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmvtt} \noindent\input{testtt}}

lcmtt\\
{\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lcmtt} \noindent\input{testtt}}

lmvtt\\
{\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmvtt} \noindent\input{testtt}}

txtt\\
{\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{txtt} \noindent\input{testtt}}

AnonymousPro\\
{\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{AnonymousPro} \noindent\input{testtt}}

Beramono\\
{\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{fvm} \noindent\input{testtt}} % Beramono

% Courier == pcr

Scaled Courier\\
{\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcrs} \noindent\input{testtt}} % Scaled Courier

DejaVuSansMono\\
{\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{DejaVuSansMono-TLF} \noindent\input{testtt}}

Droid Mono\\
{\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{fdm} \noindent\input{testtt}} % Droid Mono

Inconsolata\\
{\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{zi4} \noindent\input{testtt}} % inconsolata

KP tt\\
{\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{jkptt} \noindent\input{testtt}} % KP tt

Latin Modern\\
{\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt} \noindent\input{testtt}} % latin modern

LuxiMono\\
{\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{ul9} \noindent\input{testtt}} % LuxiMono

New TXTT\\ 
{\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{newtxtt} \noindent\input{testtt}} % New TXTT

% Optical Character Recognition Font B ?

% PX Font tt == TX Fonts == txtt ?

New TX\\
{\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{ntxtt} \noindent\input{testtt}} % New TX

qcr\\
{\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{qcr} \noindent\input{testtt}} % gyre cursor looks like courier ?

Letter Gothic\\
{\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{ulg} \noindent\input{testtt}} % Letter Gothic

zlmtt\\
{\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{zlmtt} \noindent\input{testtt}} % Latin Modern Typewriter Z

ascii\\
{\asciifamily \noindent\input{test}} % No file T1ascii.fd

\end{document}
```

Fo the `testtt.tex` file (File `test.tex` for ascii is without `{\ttfamily ... }`)

```
{\ttfamily 
Normal {\bfseries Bold} 
{\slshape Slanted} {\bfseries\slshape Slanted\&Bold} 
{\itshape Italic} {\bfseries\itshape Italic\&Bold} 
Z2 lI1 S5 O0}
```

I get the following font comparison (attention, some fonts are scaled!).

[image: Fonts comparison]