# How to set the default typewriter font?

Tags: fonts

I'd like to select a new font for the monospaced text such as those parts within a `\texttt{}` and code snippets in the `minted` context.  (As far as I can tell, `minted` just uses the document's default typewriter font, so I don't think I need to touch its settings.)  I just want to change to another monospaced font that looks all right and has a normal tilde character.  How do I do that?

Comment: `\usepackage{beramono}` for example. There are other fonts too. Which font do you want? Visit http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html` for details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the `\ttdefault` command which normally takes care of this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\texttt{How to use a typewriter font}% CM default typewriter font
\par
\renewcommand\ttdefault{cmvtt} % selects CM typewriter proportional font
\texttt{How to use a typewriter font}
\par
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr} % selects Courier font
\texttt{How to use a typewriter font}      
\end{document}
```

[image]

But indeed it's usually best to let dedicated packages as `beramamono` do this, since there can be a lot of subtleties behind fonts (of which I'm often not aware myself :-)

Comment: Refer to [fonts - Quickest way to search for valid \fontfamily arguments? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118969/quickest-way-to-search-for-valid-fontfamily-arguments) for a list of possible fontfamilies.

Answer (score 4):

`\usepackage[scaled=0.8]{FiraMono}`

Put the above line in the preamble of your document, i.e. immediately after
`\documentclass`. That's it!

Concerning the related question of what font to choose, see my answer at
[Alternative monospace fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2241/alternative-monospace-fonts#566624).

Reference:
https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html

Comment: Other fonts work this way too, like Pandora: 
`\usepackage{pandora}`

Answer (score 2):

Since this just got bumped back up to the front page, I’ll add for completeness: in `fontspec`, use `\setmonofont`.

Comment: Yeah, actually I don't have `fontspec` in my preamble (since I use just pdfLaTeX).

Comment: @Henke Which is fine!

Comment: To get a list of available fonts refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/177084/250119 (this one for Linux only, I don't know if a better question exist).